# Internet dropping in wifi, LAN - Home Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a small home network, around 4 pcs work under this network. The DSL line is hooked up to a wireless router. Problem is no one can browse the internet in the network, always getting erros, "website not found" after couple of refreshes(browser) it shows the site. When the internet line is connected directly to a pc it works fine. Also the wifi and wired network is fine, it doesn't drop or lose internet connectivity.

My internet line is 1mbps, why does my internet drops in network? is it because 1mbps is not enough for 4pcs? or is it because of a router problem?

Comment: New router? Anything change hardware wise recently? 1mbps internet is ok, unless someone/something is hogging the bandwidth with videos and such...

Comment: I asume you have windows pcs. Show the output of "ipconfig" from a pc, one time from dsl-to-pc and the other time from dsl-to-router.

Comment: 1Mbps may be too little for 1 computer, or more than enough for 8, it all depends on how the line is utilized. What kind of traffic is going over the line when the connection cuts out? Do you have another router you can use or borrow for testing? Could also be a cable issue. Do what you can to remove variables, only way you'll be able to narrow down to the cause.

Comment: @ott-- when in network http://scrp.at/bpy | direct http://scrp.at/bpz

Comment: @SahanLakshitha It must be in router settings. Can you make screenshots and put them on scrp.at too? What model is that router?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try changing WiFi channel.
2. Watch for routers Active IP connections. If 4 PC's ar running torrent, then active connections can go near the limit and then internet will drop. If it is so, you need to make limit bigger, but not too big, because router can hung. Sometimes better to lower connections timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the least amount of help, but dropping out could also be to your power supply not plugged in correctly in the back of your router, changing Wifi channels, checking your settings. If its a virgin Wireless router, they are terrible and i overcame this by purchasing a new router.

Answer (score 0):

Test your network by having only one PC in your WLAN at a time. Repeat this for all 4 PCs. In a wireless network, if only one connection becomes slow, it can potentially slow down the whole network. Let me give you an example: if you have 2 clients in a WLAN one with a 54mbps and the other one with a 1 mbps connection, the faster one cannot download/upload faster than the slower link if both want to send/receive at the same time. So, in a WLAN if one client is far from the access point (it receives a weak signal and the rate adaptation algorithm in place selects a very low data transmission rate such as 1 or 2 mbps) it can potentially slow down other clients as well. There are other reasons for a slow connection. So, make sure all local links are fast by activating only one wireless link in your network at a time.  A regular access point should be able to handle 4 clients pretty easily. Finally, have in mind that adding a new active link to a WLAN can reduce the per client performance by more than 50%. In a busy WLAN enabling RTS/CTS feature helps improving the throughput by preventing packet collision caused by concurrent transmissions.